# Display number of emails in the inbox separated by date

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I would like to display the number of emails in the inbox separated by date, and then send an email with that information to a specific user.

Everything I have here works, except for yesterday's date - it shows the number of emails +1. The other email counts are correct though.

```
Sub HowManyEmails()

    Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim EmailCount As Integer

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    On Error Resume Next

    Set objFolder = objnSpace.Folders("Mailbox - IT Support Center").Folders("NON TICKET related Emails")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        MsgBox "No such folder."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    EmailCount = objFolder.Items.Count

    MsgBox "Number of emails in the folder: " & EmailCount & " Total Non-Ticket email count"

    Dim dateStr As String
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim msg As String

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set myItems = objFolder.Items

    myItems.SetColumns ("SentOn")

    ' Determine date of each message:
    For Each myItem In myItems
        dateStr = GetDate(myItem.SentOn)
        If Not dict.Exists(dateStr) Then
            dict(dateStr) = 0
        End If
        dict(dateStr) = CLng(dict(dateStr)) + 1
    Next myItem

    ' Output counts per day:
    For Each o In dict.Keys
        msg = msg & o & ":    " & dict(o) & " Non-Ticket items" & vbCrLf
    Next

    MsgBox msg

    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objnSpace = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing

    'Send Mail
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(o)

    With OutMail
        .Subject = "Non Ticket Emails"
        .To = "johndoe@yahoo.com; Jimmydoe@schneider.com"
        .Body = msg
        .Display
        .Send
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What does `GetDate(myItem.SentOn)` do?

Comment: I'm not sure, this was copied from an existing template.

Comment: Check your code. It should be somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have found the issue. The script catches the sent time, not the received time (which outlook sorts by). I have changed senton to receivedtime in the code and it works!